# Find the indefinite integral $\int \frac{2x^2 + 1}{(2x)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus

Find the indefinite integral  $ \ \int \ \frac{2x^2 + 1}{(2x)^2} \ \ dx \ . $

I got $ \ -\frac{1}{4x} + C  \ $ but its wrong.

Comment: You forgot your $x$. That's OK. Everybody does.

Comment: Let me know if I interpreted your post correctly.  Consider that your integrand has _two_ terms, so there should be two terms in your anti-derivative (other than the arbitrary constant).  Divide the numerator through by the denominator _first_.

Comment: hint - use u-substitution

Answer (score 1):

$\int \frac{2x^2+1}{(2x)^2}dx=\int \frac12+\frac 1{(2x)^2}dx=\frac 12x+\frac14 \int x^{-2}dx=\frac 12 x-\frac 1{4x}+C$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int \frac{2x^2+1}{(2x)^2}dx&=\int \frac{2x^2+1}{4x^2} \, dx \\
&=\int \frac{2x^2}{4x^2}+\frac{1}{4x^2} \, dx & \text{split the fraction} \\
&=\int \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}x^{-2} \, dx & \text{simplify the first term} \\
&=\int \frac{1}{2} \, dx + \int \frac{1}{4}x^{-2} \, dx & \text{separate the integral} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{4} \frac{x^{-2+1}}{-2+1}+C & \text{use anti-power rule}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{4x} + C
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Break your integrand into two separate fractions.

$$\frac{2x^2 + 1}{(2x)^2} = \frac{2x^2}{(2x)^2} + \frac{1}{(2x)^2}$$